# CSS: square button in different screen resolution

Tags: html, css

Hi want to display a button as square. If I use the pixel than I have problems with the screen resolution. And if I use the percent, than the proportion in not correct

Do you know how to do this?

```
.serviceButton{
    position:absolute;
    left: 20%;
    top: 20%;
    width: 300px; //if I use this than the sqaure is small
    height: 300px; // in big screen resolutions
}


<div>
    <button type="button" class="serviceButton">Services</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, i think this fiddle helps you.. 

http://jsfiddle.net/josedvq/38Tnx/

Comment: Please read your question again and correct it where nessecary

Comment: @phpfresher : thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a nice blogpost about that [here](http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html). It will probably suit your needs, it even scales down when you shrink your window.

This is the html you'd need:

```
<div class="box square"> 
    <div class="content">Aspect ratio of 1:1</div> 
</div>
```

And add this as your css:

```
.box {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;     /* desired width */
}
.box:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
}
.square {
    padding-top: 100%; /* Play with this value for different ratios */
}
.content{
    position:  absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: nice solution. very elegant to do it this way. especially, since it is generic, has no bloat of additional markup and does not use extra ressources (like img) to enforce the ratio

Comment: The above link has expired, here's an alternate: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/07/14/css-responsive-square/